# What does this PostgreSQL query accomplish?

Tags: postgresql

I recently switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL and I noticed one additional query after following many "regular" queries.

Immediately after this...

```
SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE ("documents"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
```

this is executed:

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"documents"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
```

What does this last query accomplish? Which information is returned here?

Comment: What database access layer are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is fetching information about the table `documents`.

The catalog [pg_attribute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html) stores information about table columns.

The catalog [pg_attrdef](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalog-pg-attrdef.html) stores column default values.

- `a.attrelid`: The table this column belongs to.
- `a.attname`: The column name.
- `a.atttypid`: The data type of this column.
- `a.atttypmod`: Records type-specific data supplied at table creation time (for example, the maximum length of a varchar column). It is passed to type-specific input functions and length coercion functions. The value will generally be -1 for types that do not need atttypmod.
- `d.adsrc`: A human-readable representation of the default value.
- `a.attnotnull`: This represents a not-null constraint.

This information could for example be used by an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to construct a mapping between a class and a table in the database.